# How to tackle data truncation error when copying rows from one table to another, both tables having same schema?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

Database has two tables with same schema.

```sql
        date VARCHAR(20),
        track VARCHAR(150),
        race_number INT,
        horse_number INT,

        early_last5 FLOAT(10,1),

        PRIMARY KEY (track, race_number, horse_number, date)
```

One is named **sectional_table** and another is **window_sectional_table**.
I want to copy all contents of **sectional table** to **window_sectional_table**.
I do the most logical thing possible.

```sql
INSERT INTO window_sectional_table SELECT * FROM sectional_table;
```

Unfortunately, I am terrorized by this error.

```
Data truncated for column 'early_last5' at row 1
```

I investigate row 1. Row 1 looks like this.

```
+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| date       | track    | race_number | horse_number | early_last5 |
+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| 2021-05-03 | GUNNEDAH |           1 |            1 |         0.0 |
+------------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

How do I proceed? I believe the value 0.0 should have been auto filled for null value.

Comment: Is the `early_last5` column declared as NOT NULL? You show a summary of the columns with data types, but try `SHOW CREATE TABLE window_sectional_table\G` to see all the column options.

Answer (score 0):

The `Data truncated for column 'early_last5' at row 1` error is referring to your `INSERT` statement rather than which specific value in the database is being truncated.

> **I believe the value 0.0 should have been auto filled for null value.**

Nope. That’s not defined in your `INSERT` and it’s not defined in the table creation statement.

> **How do I proceed?**

The simplest method would be to convert the `FLOAT` value to a `DECIMAL` for the `INSERT`, complete with an `IFNULL` if you want `NULL` to be converted to 0.0. The `FLOAT` data type has long been a thorn in the side of many people who expect it to work like a typical decimal.

Here’s a quick SQL statement that should get you moving again:

```
INSERT INTO `window_sectional_table` (`date`, `track`, `race_number`, `horse_number`, `early_last5`)
SELECT `date`, `track`, `race_number`, `horse_number`,
       CAST(IFNULL(`early_last5`, 0) AS DECIMAL(10,1))
  FROM `sectional_table`
 ORDER BY `track`, `race_number`, `horse_number`, `date`;
```

Comment: Why did the error occur in the first place? What is wrong with inserting (0.0) on a float(10,1) column?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with 0.0 in a `FLOAT`. As I mentioned in the answer, the `row 1` reference was not talking about the data, but the `INSERT` statement itself 

Comment: I do not want to convert `NULL` to `0.0`. I want to copy all rows from one table to another table having identical schema. I wonder at which value this discrepancy occured. Is there any way to **debug** this ? How is this even possible? If any value was incompatible, how would it be inserted in the first table. I'm bewildered.

Comment: If you wish to keep `NULL` as is, feel free to ditch the `IFNULL`. As for “discrepancies”, it comes down to people using `FLOAT` when they really should have used a `DECIMAL`. TL;DR: `FLOAT` doesn’t do things the way most people expect, so expect the unexpected … or use a `DECIMAL` 